# Is there a way to detect Bluetooth availability without triggering Bluetooth authorization popup in iOS 13?

Tags: core-location, core-bluetooth, ios13

We're using Core Location to scan BLE beacons. Core Location has the methods to start monitoring BLE beacons, and these will respectively trigger authorization requests for Location Services. To debug problems (and instruct the user) we need a way to determine if the Core Bluetooth is, for example, turned off.

In iOS 12 (and below) it was possible to initialize `CBCentralManager` and check the state of the Bluetooth central without triggering a separate Bluetooth authorization request for the user.

Is there a way to determine Bluetooth availability, for example, from Core Location without triggering the Bluetooth authorization request?